# How to Generate a report (containing many subreports and multiple bands) using JasperReports from java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

If I have to Choose between versions, which is the most stable one?

I tried reporting with many versions. From *iReport* (any version) everything works well but when i try to compile it from my java class (The main report get compiled successfully but the subreport one doesn't get compiled cause The *JasperCompileManager* doesn't find the "subreport.jasper")

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("C://report/reportPI.jrxml");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
```

So I compiled them with *iReport 2.0.7* and used them Compiled >> the only version working with my java class is the one compiled from *iReport 2.0.7* (problem: there is no possibility of adding new band for another subreport).

The others compiled files with higher versions of *iReport* such as *4.5.1* or *4.7.0*

crash in this line

```
   JasperReport jasperReport =(JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject("C:\\report/reportPI.jasper");
```

returning

```
cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextField to field 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer of type
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParagraphContainer in instance of 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph
```

In forums they said it's jar problem, others they said it's designing error. But in my case it's something else because I tried everything with jars.

Actually i found a solution (by testing) but it's a little complicated. I compile subreports using *iReport 2.0.7* and the Main report I designed with *iReport 4.5.1* (containing many bands and many subreports) and I compile the main report by the first code.

It works **but** when i want to do many subreports under OneSubreport. I return to the same problem.

Well I think is quite detailed as question but it's necessary

If someone has a stable version where all situations work please help

After More tests..

I tried to compile a subreport.jrxml in a file by using

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign1 = JRXmlLoader.load("C://report/report74.jrxml");
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jasperDesign1, "C://report");
```

but the response `Access denied to save`.

Comment: It's not a matter of stability. From version 3, jasperreports changed the model enough to make it backwards-problematic. Both versions you deal with work fine on their own; mixing stuff raises problems with element types, properties and methods

Comment: I know!! but it's the only solution i found..thx for replying

Comment: What do you mean `ACCESS DENIED To SAVE`? Is there an actual exception? The simple answer is, you should just use the latest versions of both. Essentially you need to compile the subreports also, and then set the SUBREPOR_DIR param needs to be set to where the compiled subreport is. Should work. The other option is to not compile to a file, but to a JasperReport object and then set them as a parameter for each subreport. Then it does not have to go looking for it in the file system as it is in memory.

Comment: the fact that i compile to jasperReport is for the main report..My problem is the subreport when I compile it with Ireport latest versions when I pass it through subreport_Dir param as you said, it returns cannot assign instance of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseTextField to field 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseParagraph.paragraphContainer exception..that's why i figure out to compile it with I report 2.0.3

Comment: it's strange that with 2.0.3 it does work perfectly(each *.jasper compiled) in some forums they said that it's JAR problem but I almost TESTED them all, IF YOU ALREADY tested it can you give me suitable Jars  with I report 4.5.1...thank you